# Шаблон регулярного выражения java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка java с математическим выражением например такая

```
String str = "(((3+4)+5/8)-2+(18+5/8))-3*5";
```

Не получается написать шаблон для поиска выражения в скобках, чтобы нашло `3+4`, `18+5/8`. Подойдет и со скобками `(3+4)`. На данный момент имею вот что `"([(])([\\S]{0,5})([)])"`. Символы между скобками не пойму как записать, чтобы находило любой длины.

Comment: Разобрался сам `"[(]{1,1}[^(&&[^)]]{0,}[)]"`

Comment: Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярка для php выглядит так

```
/(?<=\()([^\(\)]+)(?=\))/
```

Пример работы https://regex101.com/r/jM3eV6/1

P.S. Для java экранируйте скобки по правилам java.